# XSD: require attributes to have specific values

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to make an XSD that specifies that an `<a>` element must have 4 child `<b>` elements, which contain the `c` attributes 1 through 4, as follows:

Valid:

```
<a>
  <b c="1" d="valueof1" />
  <b c="2" d="valueof2" />
  <b c="3" d="valueof3" />
  <b c="4" d="valueof4" />
</a>
```

Not valid:

```
<a>
  <b c="1" d="valueof1" />
  <b c="1" d="valueof1_other" />
  <b c="3" d="valueof3" />
  <b c="4" d="valueof4" />
</a>
```

Not valid:

```
<a>
  <b c="1" d="valueof1" />
  <b c="2" d="valueof2" />
  <b c="3" d="valueof3" />
  <b c="4" d="valueof4" />
  <b c="5" d="valueof5" />
</a>
```

Is this possible? The closest thing I could find is the [all](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_all.asp) element, but that only appears to work for specifying unique elements, not attribute values.

Comment: You might want to look at Schematron http://www.schematron.com/ for this sort of restriction/validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce the first rule by declaring element `b` with `minOccurs=4` and `maxOccurs=4`, like so:

```
<xs:element name="a">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="b" minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="4"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

However, you **can not use XSD** to enforce the second rule. If you really want to do that, you can, for example, replace the 4 `b` elements with elements `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, and `b4`, each of which would implicitly represent the `c` attributes 1 through 4, respectively.

Comment: You can make `a/b/@c` a key with a global uniqueness constraint and then give an integer type with facets for min=1 and max=4. Still doesn't disallow `1, 3, 2, 4` though...